# Auto filling of OTP is happening,but unable to verify when auto filling is used where as i am able to verify when OTP is entered manually

Tags: flutter, autofill, one-time-password

Auto filling of OTP is happening,but unable to verify when auto filling is used  where as I am able to verify when OTP is entered manually

Here is my code for OTP  autofilling

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sms_autofill/sms_autofill.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mvc_pattern/mvc_pattern.dart';
import 'package:otp_text_field/otp_field.dart';
import 'package:otp_text_field/style.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:sms_autofill/sms_autofill.dart';
import 'package:multisuperstore/src/controllers/user_controller.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:multisuperstore/generated/l10n.dart';

class VerifyOTPScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  String verificationId;
  String mobileNo;
  VerifyOTPScreen({
    this.verificationId,
    this.mobileNo,
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<VerifyOTPScreen> createState() => _VerifyOTPScreenState();
}

class _VerifyOTPScreenState extends State<VerifyOTPScreen> with CodeAutoFill {
  String codeValue = "";

  @override
  void codeUpdated() {
    print("Update code $code");
    setState(() {
      print("codeUpdated");
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    listenOtp();
  }

  void listenOtp() async {
    // await SmsAutoFill().unregisterListener();
    // listenForCode();
    await SmsAutoFill().listenForCode;
    print("OTP listen Called");
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    SmsAutoFill().unregisterListener();
    print("unregisterListener");
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Center(
              child: PinFieldAutoFill(
                currentCode: codeValue,
                codeLength: 4,

                onCodeChanged: (code) {
                  print("onCodeChanged $code");
                  setState(() {
                    codeValue = code.toString();
                  });
                },
                onCodeSubmitted: (val) {
                  print("onCodeSubmitted $val");
                },
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print(codeValue);
                },
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
                    padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.all(20)),
                    textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(TextStyle(fontSize: 25))),

                child: const Text("Verify OTP"),   ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: listenOtp,style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
                padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.all(20)),
                textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(TextStyle(fontSize: 25))), child: const Text("Resend"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the code for manually  entering OTP and verifying please suggest the changes

```
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:multisuperstore/src/controllers/user_controller.dart';
import 'package:mvc_pattern/mvc_pattern.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:otp_text_field/otp_field.dart';
import 'package:otp_text_field/style.dart';

import '../../generated/l10n.dart';
import 'package:sms_autofill/sms_autofill.dart';





// ignore: must_be_immutable
class OtpVerificationSmart extends StatefulWidget {
  String verificationId;
  String mobileNo;
  OtpVerificationSmart({
    Key key,
    this.verificationId,
    this.mobileNo,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OtpVerificationSmartState createState() => _OtpVerificationSmartState();
}

class _OtpVerificationSmartState extends StateMVC<OtpVerificationSmart> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller1;
  final TextEditingController _controllerOTPPhone = TextEditingController();
  bool isPlaying = true;
  UserController _con;
  _OtpVerificationSmartState() : super(UserController()) {
    _con = controller;
  }
  String get timerString {
    Duration duration = controller1.duration * controller1.value;
    String timer = '${duration.inMinutes}:${(duration.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';

    if (timer == '0:00') {
      isPlaying = false;
    }
    return '${duration.inMinutes}:${(duration.inSeconds % 300).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller1 = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 60),
    );

    controller1.reverse(from: controller1.value == 0.0 ? 1.0 : controller1.value);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('OTP ${S.of(context).verification}',style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,),
      ),
      key: _con.scaffoldKey,
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _con.loginFormKey,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Align(
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                    child:Image.asset('assets/img/cart_empty_ipmau1.png',
                      width: 150,height:150,fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    )
                ),
              ),

              Text(S.of(context).verification_code, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1.merge(TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              Text("${S.of(context).we_have_sent_the_code_verification_to_your_mobile_number} ${widget.mobileNo}",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center, ),

              SizedBox(height: 20),






              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:20,left: 20, right: 20),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Flexible(
                          child: OTPTextField(
                            length: 6,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            textFieldAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            fieldWidth: 40,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                            fieldStyle: FieldStyle.underline,
                            onCompleted: (pin) {
                              _controllerOTPPhone.text = pin;
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              SizedBox(height: 43.0),

              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left:20,right:20),
                // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                child:RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    // Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/SignUp', );
                    PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential =
                    PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                        verificationId: widget.verificationId, smsCode: _controllerOTPPhone.text);

                    _con.signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
                  },
                  shape: StadiumBorder(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  child: Ink(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                       color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                    child: Container(

                      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: double.infinity, minHeight: 50.0),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text(S.of(context).verify,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4.merge(TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight))),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),),
              SizedBox(height: 80.0),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TimerPainter extends CustomPainter {
  TimerPainter({
    this.animation,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.color,
  }) : super(repaint: animation);

  final Animation<double> animation;
  final Color backgroundColor, color;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = backgroundColor
      ..strokeWidth = 3.0
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    canvas.drawCircle(size.center(Offset.zero), size.width / 2.0, paint);
    paint.color = color;
    double progress = (1.0 - animation.value) * 2 * math.pi;
    canvas.drawArc(Offset.zero & size, math.pi * 1.5, -progress, false, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(TimerPainter old) {
    return animation.value != old.animation.value || color != old.color || backgroundColor != old.backgroundColor;
  }
}
```

Please help me with the code under onPressed event for Verify OTP button

Comment: Just got canfused as to How and what to give or code in the OnPressed Click event for the Verify OTP  Text  button when OTP is auto filled. It is verifying perfectly when OTP is filled manuallly.

Comment: Hi I am eagerly waiting for the solution or fix to my query.

Comment: Only Help me with the code for onPressed: {}   event for this situation